# Calculate the birth year in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to calculate the Birth year's of any age, but i could not do it like this.
And i did't see any error and the calculate function is work  but it doesn't output any value.I think the error is in calculation function..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>BirthDate</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>

<body style="background-color: #bfc5c5">
  <form style="margin-top:10px">
    <input type="number" name="number" style="height:30px;width: 400px;padding-left: 10px" placeholder="type your age" id="number">
    <input type="button" value="find year" id="button" style="height: 35px">
    <p id="year">year</p>
  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function calculate() {
      var number = document.getElementById("number").value;

      if (number == "" || number == 0) {
        window.alert("Please type your correct age!");
        return;
      }

      var date = new(Date()).getFullYear()
      var birthyear = number - date;

      document.getElementById("year").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = "Your Birth Year is " + birthyear;

    }

    document.getElementById("year").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("button").onclick = function {
      calculate();
    };
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you've got a syntax error. start by fixing that.

Comment: see the error in the console? `"message": "SyntaxError: missing ( before formal parameters",`

Answer (score 1):

You're leaving out `new` from the Date constructor wrapped in parenthesis:

```
var date = (new Date()).getFullYear();
```

And missing a set of parenthesis for your `onClick` event handler:

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've two error in your code, when you fix them all goes right :

1. Function missing the parentheses `()` at :

   ```
    document.getElementById("button").onclick = function  {
    ____________________________________________________^^
   ```

   Should be :

   ```
    document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
   ```
2. The definition of your date has extra parentheses `()` in :

   ```
   var date = new(Date()).getFullYear();
   ______________^______^
   ```

   Should be :

   ```
   var date = new Date().getFullYear();
   ```

### Working Snippet :

```js
function calculate() {
  var number = document.getElementById("number").value;

  if (number == "" || number == 0) {
    window.alert("Please type your correct age!");
    return;
  }

  var date = new Date().getFullYear()
  var birthyear = number - date;

  document.getElementById("year").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = "Your Birth Year is " + birthyear;
}


document.getElementById("year").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
  calculate();
};
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #bfc5c5;
}
```

```html
<form style="margin-top:10px">
  <input type="number" name="number" style="height:30px;width: 400px;padding-left: 10px" placeholder="type your age" id="number">
  <input type="button" value="find year" id="button" style="height: 35px">
  <p id="year">year</p>
</form>
```

Comment: It all goes right as long as you don't mind the birth year being negative because the `var birthyear` calculation has the age and year reversed.